# SQL INNER JOIN does not see table alias

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT linkstable.date, (linkstable.count - x.count) 
FROM (SELECT .....) AS linkstable 
INNER JOIN linkstable AS x 
  ON linkstable.date = x.date+1
```

It tells me that links table cannot be found although (SQL error 1146) there clearly is an alias to that select query. Can anybody tell me please how do I bypass this error?

Comment: Are you trying to join your subquery to itself?  What database are you using?

Comment: What type of SQL are you using?

Comment: [The error message seems to indicate MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1146).

Comment: do you have `linkstable` table in your schema? you cannot select from alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot alias an alias. If you want to join table to itself, repeat the select:

```
SELECT linkstable.date, (linkstable.count - x.count) 
FROM (SELECT .....) AS linkstable 
INNER JOIN (SELECT .....) AS x ON linkstable.date = x.date+1
```

If inner select is too cumbersome or you're running into performance issues insert its results into a temp table and use it in your main query.

Comment: The link I gave you was bad. Here's the [SQL server 2008](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/8639) and  the [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee7da/6937)

Comment: @ConradFrix these assume that linkstable is a table and not just an alias?

Comment: @msmucker0527 you're right. The OP needs to clear that up. Of course the OP should also clear up the RDBMS. For example if this was SQL 2008 and my assumption is wrong then I'd use a Common table expression not a temp table or table varible. But if it's MySQL then Yuriy is correct.

Comment: @ConradFrix I believe OP uses MySQL, also try naming your aliases different form actual table name: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/8642 and see if it works in SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Yuriy then I [write it this way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/8643) but we need to wait for the OP to clarify

Comment: The linkstable is just an alias it doesn't actually exist in the data base. Is there a reason for which I cannot "alias an alias" like you said?

Comment: @ConradFrix That's another story :) post that as an answer. Not sure if MySQL supports CTE tho

Comment: @YuriyGalanter it doesn't :(

Comment: Holy c**p it worked. I'm going to try and find out why the previous query was defective. Thanks a lot to all for the prompt responses! I think it's mySQL, but I'm a total noob at this. However it seemed like a SQL language error rather than a mySQL screw-up

Answer (score 4):

You can't reference a subquery's alias in the `FROM` clause like that. However, if your database supports Common Table Expressions, you can use the `WITH` clause to accomplish the same thing:

```
WITH linkstable as (SELECT ...)
SELECT linkstable.date, (linkstable.count - x.count) 
FROM linkstable 
INNER JOIN linkstable AS x 
  ON linkstable.date = x.date+1
```